# Connect to Bluetooth device working on Marshmallow device but not Oreo device, why?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am making an app, that communicates with a specific Arduino HC06 bluetooth module.

I have been testing this app on my Samsung S5 Neo with Marshmallow, and now when i am mostly done, i wanted to try out on my main phone, Xiaomi Redmi 5 running android Oreo. But it doesn't work. I have had one succesful connection from my Oreo phone to the HC06 module, beside that it will not connect.

What i have done so far:

I have made sure that my Oreo phone and HC06 module are paired.
I have added some extra permissions via runtime. I have these permissions so far:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I can't figure out why this is working on the older phone i have, but not the new one. I hope someone can guide me in the right direction, thank you.

This is the method I use to find bluetooth and connect to bluetooth

```
void findBT() {
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast errore = makeText(MachineReady.this, "Error, enable bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        errore.show();
    }

    if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            mmDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.e("Bluetooth", "Bluetooth device found01");
    //Toast found = makeText(MachineReady.this, "Bluetooth device found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    //found.show();
}

void openBT() throws IOException {
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();
    if(mmSocket.isConnected()){
        beginListenForData();
        bluConnection = true;
        //Toast opened = makeText(MachineReady.this, "Bluetooth is opened with" + mmDevice + mmSocket, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //opened.show();
        Log.e("Bluetooth", "Bluetooth connection has been established4");

        try {
            msg = "1";
            mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
            //Toast b = Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //b.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Send bluetooth", "Couldn't send text");
        }

    }else if(!mmSocket.isConnected()){
        Toast notOpened = makeText(MachineReady.this, "Bluetooth couldn't connect to the device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        notOpened.show();
    }
```

In the Log i receive an exception saying this: "Couldn't find or connect to bluetooth" which is coming from this

```
try {
            findBT();
            openBT();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Bluetooth", "Couldn't find or connect to bluetooth");
        }
```

Comment: Your loop for searching Bluetooth devices in `findBT()` is quite strange...it just stops immediately after the first element in the list. You need to filter for the right one that you want to use before breaking the loop.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.. This was also the answer, i now fixed the problem by using the example on android developer website. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

As stated by ecle, my method for finding or searching for the bluetooth unit was not working properly.

i use this one instead:

```
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter
            .getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevices.isEmpty()) {
        Log.e("bluetooth",
                "No devices paired...");
        return ;
    }

    String MY_MAC_ADDR = getResources().getString(R.string.Bluetooth_MAC);

    for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
        Log.d("Bluetooth", "Device : address : " + device.getAddress() + " name :"
                + device.getName());
        if (MY_MAC_ADDR.equals(device.getAddress())) {
            mmDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }
```

I am now looking for a specific bluetooth device using the MAC address

And now it works perfectly.
Thank you ecle for pointing this out.